# How do fb ads projects collect data?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, ads

this is more a general question, but does anyone know, how websites like http://dropispy.com/ collect fb ads data and allow you to query FB ads data in time (week/month/year ago)?

An obvious answer would be - with FB Ads api, but with it, you have to query FB pages and can not query back in time.

Comment: If they are not scraping stuff, then they are probably doing it via https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api/

Comment: _“and can not query back in time”_ – no one’s stopping them from storing what data they queried today, into their own databases, so that they can include it in the search results you see in a month from now, right?